# `apt update` shows `a` after pressing Enter

Tags: apt

When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run `sudo apt update`, terminal shows `a`

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does your password start with `a`? Did you start entering password after pressing Enter? Did you wait enough for `[sudo] password for...` prompt?

Comment: Issue solved, After upgrade whole system from Ubuntu 20.10 to Ubuntu 21.04 beta, thank you